# Python: how can I get negative indices out for index(str, beg=0, end=len(string)), i.e. counting from end

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

For the following list and string:

```
listb = ['b','c','d','e']
listb.index('d')
... 2

listb.index('e')
... 3

word1 = 'hellomatico'

word1.index('t')
... 7
```

All the indices are from left, none from right (negative). Negative indices would be -2, -1, -4 respectively.
How can I force the list.index(...) or string.index(...) to give me a negative index output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all you have to do is subtract the length of the string or list from the .index result value.

```
>>> word1.index('t')-(len(word1))
-4
>>> word1[-4]
't'
```

You can also create a method for it.

```
negative_index(word, char):
    return word.index(char) - len(word)
```

Works for both string and list.

And then just invoke it:

```
index = negative_index(word1, 't')
```

Comment: Thanks, that sure works. I was, however, hoping for a more elegant solution, especially for the case where I would have to key this in many times in code.

Comment: well if by elegant you mean a built-in method I'm afraid i'm not able to find one, as there is reverse index , but all it does it's finding elements from the last position to the first but will still give you a positive index for the first found element.

You could however transform it into a method and return its value, something in the lines of 

negative_index( word , char ):
     return word.index(char) - len(word)